# HQL JOIN Problem

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have 2 classes: **ClassRoom**, **Student**

```
Class Student {
 private Integer id;
 private ClassRoom classRoom;
 private String name;

 /* GETTERS AND SETTER */
}


Class ClassRoom{
 private Integer id;
 private Set<Student> students;

 /* GETTERS AND SETTER */
}
```

What is the **HQL** to select all ClassRooms which have studens called **John**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
select distinct ClassRoom
from Student
where Name = 'John'
```

Option 2:

```
from ClassRoom c
where c in (select ClassRoom
            from Student
            where Name = 'John')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from ClassRoom inner join Student as student where student.name = 'John'
```

You will need to use the fully qualified (with namespaces) names for your class.

Also, if the name is coming from the client, you should use a parameter (eg. :name)

Comment: By the way, this is pretty basic HQL. You should have a skim through the documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm using HQL very similar to this in a project that I am working on at the moment and it executes just fine.